# Equivalent to checkrestart for CentOS?

Tags: centos, debian, centos6

[This](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/checkrestart.1.html) is `checkrestart`.

> check which processes need to be restarted after an upgrade

Are there any packages which provide that functionality?
Hopefully obvious, but [this answer](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=17947) is completely unacceptable. I can't rely on the package maintainer of every single library on my system to separately check whether services are using that library, and then force a restart of those services on the offchance that I would guess restarting those services would be fine.

Answer (score 6):

There is a Python script shipped with the `yum-utils` package, called `needs-restarting`, that can print out the processes that need to be restarted after an upgrade.

Comment: maybe worth noting that it does not properly check everything: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1131307